# stdClass object and foreach loops

Tags: php, object, foreach, stdclass

I am using the following code to get data from a website using Soap.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://some.url.here');
class SMSParam {
    public $CellNumber;
    public $AccountKey;
    public $MessageCount;
    public $MessageBody;
    public $Reference;

}
$parameters = new SMSParam;
$parameters -> AccountKey = "$sms_key";
$parameters -> MessageCount = "25";
$Result = $client->GetIncomingMessages($parameters);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($Result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Here is a sample of the output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetIncomingMessagesResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [SMSIncomingMessage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [OutgoingMessageID] => data
                            [Reference] => data
                            [MessageNumber] => data
                            [PhoneNumber] => data
                            [Message] => data
                            [ReceivedDate] => data
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [OutgoingMessageID] => data
                            [Reference] => data
                            [MessageNumber] => data
                            [PhoneNumber] => data
                            [Message] => data
                            [ReceivedDate] => data
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [OutgoingMessageID] => data
                            [Reference] => data
                            [MessageNumber] => data
                            [PhoneNumber] => data
                            [Message] => data
                            [ReceivedDate] => data
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

If only 1 result is returned, I can simply do something like this:

```
$reference = $result->GetIncomingMessagesResult->SMSIncomingMessage->Reference;
```

So how would I go about working with multiple results?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 41):

It is an array, so you can loop over it easily using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($result->GetIncomingMessagesResult->SMSIncomingMessage as $message) {
    echo $message->Reference;
}
```

However it is worth noting that PHP's `SoapClient` by default appears to return arrays as a PHP array only when there is more than one value in the array - if there is only one value you will just get that value (not contained within an array). An easy way around this is to  use the option `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` in the `SoapClient` constructor; this will prevent this behaviour and ensure you always get arrays.

Comment: Spent the day yesterday puzzled over this very thing. I had no idea about the "SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS" flag; thanks for that.

Comment: for people who don't know how to add the option : `$client = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com', array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,));`

Answer (score 3):

My take on it is to just always make sure you have an array of messages, even if it's an array of 1.  That way you don't duplicate any processing.

```
$smsMessages = is_array( $result->GetIncomingMessagesResult->SMSIncomingMessage )
    ? $result->GetIncomingMessagesResult->SMSIncomingMessage
    : array( $result->GetIncomingMessagesResult->SMSIncomingMessage );

foreach ( $smsMessages as $smsMessage )
{
    echo $smsMessage->Reference;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify your SMSIncomingMessage arrays object key.

```
$result->GetIncomingMessagesResult->SMSIncomingMessage[0]->Reference;
```

or

```
foreach ($result->GetIncomingMessagesResult->SMSIncomingMessage as $message)
{
$reference = $message[0]->Reference;
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array?! :-)

```
foreach ($result->GetIncomingMessagesResult->SMSIncomingMessage as $message)
{
    $reference = $message->Reference;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast object to convert array

```
$array = (array) json_decode(['TEST'=>true]);
```