# Looping through a object(stdClass)

Tags: php, object

I saw this exmaple but still not sure how to go about it

The problem is that they transposed the table into column -> row instead of row -> column, you can do that by creating a new table and reverse the columns and rows.

```
$table = array();

foreach ($result['xxx']->Columns->Column as $colnr => $coldata) {
    foreach ($coldata->Rows->string as $rownr => $rowdata) {
        $table[$rownr][$coldata->Name] = $rowdata;
    }
}
```

print_r($table);

Could some assist me on looping through this data , planning to display the data as table
result with var_dump($result->result);

```
object(stdClass) #5 (1) { 
    ["complexObjectArray"]= > array(5) {
        [0] = > object(stdClass) #6 (105) { 
            ["increment_id"]= > string(9) "100000118" 
            ["store_id"] = > string(1) "1" 
            ["created_at"] = > string(19) "2013-04-21 07:14:34"
        }
        [1] = > object(stdClass) #7 (104) { 
            ["increment_id"]= > string(9) "100000128" 
            ["store_id"] = > string(1) "1" 
            ["created_at"] = > string(19) "2013-04-22 09:50:27" 
        }
        [2] = > object(stdClass) #8 (105) { 
            ["increment_id"]= > string(9) "100000133" 
            ["store_id"] = > string(1) "1" 
            ["created_at"] = > string(19) "2013-04-24 07:43:40" 
            ["updated_at"] = > string(19) "2013-04-27 14:50:23" 
        }
        [3] = > object(stdClass) #9 (108) { 
            ["increment_id"]= > string(9) "100000156" 
            ["store_id"] = > string(1) "1" 
            ["created_at"] = > string(19) "2013-05-07 14:41:30" 
        } 
    }
}
```

I was thinking of something around this

```
    foreach($result as $complexObj){
foreach($complexObj as $totalArray){
foreach($totalArray as $item){

echo $item->["increment_id"];
}
}
}
```

Comment: @dleiftah thanks for formatting it, i was figuring how to do that :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($result->result->complexObjectArray as $item){
    echo $item->increment_id;
}
```

Comment: not showing anything , even var_dump($item). I'm looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950827/stdclass-object-and-foreach-loops  it seems very similar to my issue , i'm trying to understand it :(

Comment: @RainbowHat If `var_dump($result)` produces the dump you have above, then this should work. Try doing a `var_dump($result->complexObjectArray)` before the loop ... that should display the array that you're wanting to loop over. If it doesn't, then `$result` is not in the structure you posted above

Comment: It says NULL var_dump($result->complexObjectArray) before loop

Comment: Then `$result` does not contain the dump you provided above. What variable is the dump from? What do you get when you dump `$result`?

Comment: Above is actually var_dump($result->result); sorry :x

Comment: var_dump($result); will give additional code(at the very front) object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["result"]=>

Comment: var_dump($result->result->complexObjectArray); will give me array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (105) { ["increment_id"]=> string(9) "100000118" etc

Comment: I have updated the loop above to account for the variable structure. Give that a shot ...

Comment: Yap, I figured it out, Thank you ! I believe i can now display it like a table. Thank you so much @dleiftah , so nice of you. I learnt something important today (Y)