# PHP loop through array of stdClass object

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I have a query that I run in MySQL and it returns a result as an `stdClass` object as following :

```
array(8){
  [
    0
  ]=>object(stdClass)#36(1){
    [
      "color"
    ]=>string(7)"#a0a0a0"
  }[
    1
  ]=>object(stdClass)#35(1){
    [
      "color"
    ]=>string(7)"#e0e0e0"
  }[
    2
  ]=>object(stdClass)#30(1){
    [
      "color"
    ]=>string(7)"#f0f0f0"
  }[
    3
  ]=>object(stdClass)#37(1){
    [
      "color"
    ]=>string(7)"#f0f0f1"
  }[
    4
  ]=>object(stdClass)#34(1){
    [
      "color"
    ]=>string(7)"#404040"
  }[
    5
  ]=>object(stdClass)#38(1){
    [
      "color"
    ]=>string(7)"#c0c0c0"
  }[
    6
  ]=>object(stdClass)#39(1){
    [
      "color"
    ]=>string(7)"#e06080"
  }[
    7
  ]=>object(stdClass)#40(1){
    [
      "color"
    ]=>string(7)"#e06082"
  }
}
```

I would like to get the colors values. How can I loop through this object and get each hex color to store in an array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [stdClass object and foreach loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950827/stdclass-object-and-foreach-loops)

Comment: `foreach ($array as $obj) { echo $obj->color; }`

Comment: @JamieTaylor That question bears no resemblance to this one and the solutions won't help.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski How so? they both seem to be similar to me. The most upvoted answer explains the foreach loop within stdClass objects well too. Apologies for my confusion.

Comment: Why put your data into that data array of objects structure at all?  I think I would just query the data and load values your are interested in into a numerically indexed array from the start.

Comment: @JamieTaylor This requires a loop on the outer array. It's really just a matter of the OP not understanding the data structure.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I suppose, I would argue it's still quite a similar solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy enough.  Loop through the array and access the object and the color property and assign it to a new array element:

```
foreach($array as $object) {
    $colors[] = $object->color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a `foreach` loop and iterate through the array. Since each array element is an object you can do it like so:

```
$array = //results from query    
foreach($array as $obj) {
    echo $obj->color;
}
```